# Add Image on TableViewController till Search bar is inactive

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying something and don't know if I am on a right track. 
I have a `UITableViewController` added to `ViewController`. My table have multiple sections and I would like my table to be empty till the `UISearchBar` is inactive. Which I have already accomplished.

I would like to add multiple images to the blank screen in the bottom till the search bar is active, so the screen is not blank.

How do I add images to this screen till I click the search bar and hide the images once I click the search bar and populate the table.

[image]

Comment: Is your question regarding the images or the searching or ….?

Comment: image! I want to show images and once the search bar is active the images disappears and populate the actual table!

Comment: Do you see how you don't actually ask a question in your question?

Comment: I edited. hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add imagesViews to your view controller's view. Set your search bar's delegate to your view controller subclass. Then say something like:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar){
   self.imageView.hidden = true
}
```

And

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar){
   if searchBar.text.length() == 0{
      self.imageView.hidden = false
   }
}
```

Comment: You got the false and true statement switched. first one should be true and second one should be false. Otherwise it works! Thanks. I was on the right track but I was trying to manually add the imageView to the ViewController which didn't work because UITableView was messing it up. Can you fix it so I can put this as an answer.